# Create Rule controls become hidden in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco

I'm going through Developer's Guide 5x example code. After I finished following section: Creating an action configurable in Alfresco Share, I deployed and restart Tomcat. Unfortunately something went wrong with Create rule form in Alfresco Share, rule controls become hidden. Below is a screenshot of the form. What could be a problem? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please add the example code

Comment: Thanks for reading the book. Please specify exactly which version of Alfresco you are using.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm using Alfresco 5.2.2. The problem was in the script RuleConfigActionCustom.js There is a missing code in the guide.